# How to open alert dialog if not getting response from server in 30 seconds in android?

Tags: android, web-services

```
public class AllDataAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getData(params[0].toString());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);        


        if (isNetworkConnected() == true) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();           
            adapter = new NewsScreenAdapter(NewsScreenActivity.this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

          } else if(isNetworkConnected() == false) {

             // runDialog(seconds);     
                AlertDialog connection = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        NewsScreenActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("No Network Found")
                        .setMessage(
                                "Internet Connection Reqired To Use this Application")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {

                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }).create();

                connection.show(); 
            }       
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsScreenActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loding ...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.

            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            // " Internet Connection Reqired To Use this Application",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Network Found",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }

}
```

Hello friends, I wanna open alert if not getting response from server in 30 sec. How can I do that in asyncTask. I have already check internet connectivity, but I want to check response also..so please anybody can tell me how is that possible..thanks..